# pyAudio pop sound between loop

Tags: python

- Original code, without my modifications is from [HERE](https://www.dobitaobyte.com.br/streaming-de-audio-com-esp8266/) but also have the same issue

Hi everyone

> *I hear pop sounds* -
> *How often do you see them?*
> -*All the time*

The code works fine, I think I know the problem. What happens is that I hear a click / pop sound almost constantly. I think that the delay between getting the data from UDP and streaming it to pyAydio, makes the audio instance start and stop, start and stop, on loop, and that's make "pop" on the output, because I dont hear it on the final wav file.

I dont know how to make pyAudio stay "on" even if data is not available yet. I'm new on python, so first sorry if I'm asking something dumb

Thanks for the attention, the code is right down below.

EDIT: I'm trying to use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) but I think that I'm only complicating everything (stuck trying to figure out how communicate the variables between the loops )

```
import pyaudio
import socket
import sys
import wave
from datetime import datetime 
import time 

UDP_IP = "0.0.0.0"
UDP_PORT = 1234

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

FORMAT = 32
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 8000
CHUNK = 1024
frames = []

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, output=True)
print("Listening", UDP_IP)

def save_wav():
    print ("saving...")
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

    waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME + '.wav', 'wb')
    waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
    waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    waveFile.close()

try:
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(CHUNK)
        #print (data)
        stream.write(data)
        frames.append(data)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt Ctrl+C")
    save_wav()
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    stream.terminate()
```